# C# reflected type as type parameter

Tags: c#

I have a `Type`, which I parsed from it's fully qualified name:

`Type paramType = Type.GetType(param.TypeName);`

How can I use `paramType` to create an instance of an object with `paramType` as a type parameter?

Comment: [Activator.CreateInstance Method @ learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance)

Comment: why not to use ( var )

Comment: @AlaaMohammed obviously because it's only helps when compiler can determine  type at COMPILE TIME

Comment: @AlaaMohammed - How would you use `var`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
void Main()
{
    Type typeParam = typeof(int);
    Type typeGeneric = typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType(typeParam);
    
    object foo = Activator.CreateInstance(typeGeneric);
    //foo is a Foo<int>
}

public class Foo<T>
{
    
}
```